# Set htaccess redirect based on query string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo

I want to redirect old pages like this:

http://www.agriturismoborgobiaia.it/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=47&Itemid=54&lang=en

to

http://www.agriturismoborgobiaia.it/

Only if query string contains certains value.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want to redirect or rewrite? if you redirect you will always display the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have to use mod_rewrite of apache (or whatever your engine is)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} <a regex here>
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.agriturismoborgobiaia.it/ [R,L]
```

Look at [Clean URL](http://wettone.com/code/clean-urls), [Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/misc/rewriteguide.html) and [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) as references :

Answer (score 0):

In your `.htaccess`

```
Redirect 301 oldpage newpage
```

Comment: And what about : quoting> Only if query string contains certains value.